# Evaluation of derivative in unit vector Notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute the derivative of $r(t)=<3t,4\sin(t),4\cos(t)>$ and write your answer in standard unit vector notation.

What i try::

$$r'(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg<3t,4\sin(t),4\cos(t)\bigg>$$

$$r'(t)=\bigg<3,4\cos(t),-4\sin(t)\bigg>$$

Then $$\hat{r'(t)}=\frac{r'(t)}{|r'(t)|}=\frac{1}{5}\bigg<3t,4\sin(t),4\cos(t)\bigg>$$

Is my solution is Right or i multiply $\hat{r'(t)}$ by a factor of $5$. Plesse Help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\vec r'=3~ \vec i +4 \sin t~ \vec j+4\cos t ~\vec k$$
$$\hat r'=\frac{3~ \vec i +4 \cos t~ \vec j-4\sin t ~\vec k}{5}$$